# Program does not run but says process completed

Tags: java, user-interface, panel, frame

I'm making gui version of the game FLAMES and I think the code is already correct because build output says process completed but it does not show my program. It's my first time encountering this problem, any advice? I'm using JDK if that helps

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Event;
import java.awt.Frame;
public class  guiflames{public static void main(String []args){int q=0;
JButton btn1= new JButton("Done");
     btn1.addActionListener( new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {  

    final JFrame frame1= new JFrame("NAMES");
    final JPanel panel1= new JPanel();
    frame1.setSize(350,350);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    frame1.setResizable(false);
    frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.add(panel1);

    Label name1= new Label("Enter the first name :");
    final TextField txt1= new TextField(30);


    Label name2= new Label("Enter the second name :");
    final TextField txt2= new TextField(30);
    JButton btn1= new JButton("Done");


                panel1.add(name1);
                panel1.setBackground(Color.pink);
                panel1.add(txt1);
                panel1.add(name2);
                panel1.add(txt2);
                panel1.add(btn1);
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ?

Comment: Please provide an SSCCE. See the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @sanshai28 what do you mean?

Comment: You need to provide the code which should run/start the gui. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: You are accessing a button in a same name of action button in panel (panel(btn1)). change the name of that button.

Comment: Creating swing components as local variables in your main function isn't the right approach to building a GUI. You might want to start here. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Answer (score 0):

Unless you haven't copied and pasted your code properly, the error is that you're created the `JFrame` in the `actionListener` of a button, which is never added to a visible frame.

The offending lines of code are:

```
JButton btn1= new JButton("Done");
btn1.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        final JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("NAMES");
```

Your code doesn't indicate where the `ActionListener` ends, but I'm guessing this isn't what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to place the whole frame outside the actionListener and it worked but the labels did not show, so i'm guessing that I also need to place that outside the actionListener? Sorry if its such a stupid question

Comment: What is it you want to happen when you click the button? What should your main frame display when it starts?

Comment: I want the results of the game to be shown in a new frame which will be over the main frame. I added the new frame before closing the actionListener...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the the flames frame to be displayed directly, you can try something like this (Have just removed the button you have initialized in the main class),

```
public static void main(String []args){

            final JFrame frame1= new JFrame("NAMES");
            final JPanel panel1= new JPanel();
            frame1.setSize(350,350);
            frame1.setVisible(true);
            frame1.setResizable(false);
            frame1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame1.add(panel1);

            Label name1= new Label("Enter the first name :");
            final TextField txt1= new TextField(30);


            Label name2= new Label("Enter the second name :");
            final TextField txt2= new TextField(30);
            JButton btn1= new JButton("Done");


                        panel1.add(name1);
                        panel1.setBackground(Color.pink);
                        panel1.add(txt1);
                        panel1.add(name2);
                        panel1.add(txt2);
                        panel1.add(btn1);


        }
```